# CSS: перенос элементов

Tags: css3, html, javascript, css

Существует решение для построения дерева с использованием HTML + CSS. Еще немного JS используется для реализации функции свертывания узлов дерева.

[Вот](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45737419/CSS3_Family_Tree/tree.html) собственно и сам пример.

Проблема в том, что при большом количестве узлов, последние [не помещаются](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45737419/CSS3_Family_Tree/other/Screenshot%20from%202013-12-04%2017%3A02%3A53.png) в родительский контейнер. Можете предложить какие-то идеи по устранению данной проблемы? Что только не пробовал: и работал со свойством overflow и javascript задействовал - безрезультатно.

Буду рад как готовому решению, так и его словесному описанию. Заранее спасибо.

*P.S.: Оригинал - [CSS3 Family Tree](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree)*

Comment: Может стоит раскрывать лишь 1ну из ветвей, а другие сворачивать?
Т.е: открываешь 1вую, смотришь, открываешь вторую - 1вая сворачивается, открываешь 5тую - 2рая сворачивается и т.д. 
Одна активная (раскрытая), а другие свернуты

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно применю это решение. Оно решает проблему, но лишь частично. Ведь есть узлы, которые не помещаются в контейнер даже если остальные(не родительские) свернуты, как и показано на скриншоте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть одна мысль. Сделать

```
ul { white-space: nowrap; }
li { display: inline-block!important; }
```

Но надо будет тогда css крепко править, чтобы нужный вид со всеми линиями сохранился